# Designating a Column for an Operation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am not a coder, but am working with pandas in python 3 to modify a program someone else wrote to strip HTML out of a column in a CSV file. In the original code, it asked for user input for the column names as in the code at the bottom, but my csv file will always have the same column headings so I would prefer not to have this input step, instead just including the column name in the program itself.

I have tried to replace this line:

```
col = input("Enter column name: ")
```

which works exactly the way it is supposed to when I manually input the column name (outputting a new column with the HTML cleaned), with:

```
col = df['ColumnName']
```

and many other variations, but whatever I try gives me various errors. What syntax should I use to simply have it operate directly on the column I name rather than requiring the manual input. Thanks so much for the help.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import html
def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.+?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, ' ', str(raw_html))
    clean = re.sub('\s+',' ',cleantext)
    return html.unescape(clean)
file = input("Enter CSV File name (without '.csv' at the end): ")
d = pd.read_csv("%s.csv" % file )
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
col = input("Enter column name: ")
df[col][0:5]
df['clean'] = df[col].apply(cleanhtml)
```

Comment: After `col = input("Enter column name: ")`, `col` contains the *name* of the column. If you want it to be static, you should use `col = 'ColumnName'`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much, Serge.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

instead of manually accepting column names, you can just replace the input command with the name of the column that you want i.e

```
col = input("Enter column name: ")
```

with

```
col = 'columnName'
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks so much.